# Unable to delete database record where multiple rows have same column value?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have a Table where i have multiple rows with same column name like below,

```
ID   Column1   Column2   Column3

1     test     value1    katy

2     test     value2    kavita

3     test     value3    henry

4     test     value4    stalin
```

i used the below technique to retrieve the record and tried to delete them but it say cast error,

```
TableName DeleteSession = (TableName)from s in Data.TableName where s.Column1 == "test"  select s;

Data.TabelName.DeleteOnSubmit(DeleteSession);
Data.SubmitChanges();
```

how to delete rows with same colum name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var DeleteSession = (from s in Data.TableName 
                     where s.Column1 == "test"  
                     select s).ToList();

Data.TabelName.DeleteAllOnSubmit(DeleteSession);
Data.SubmitChanges();
```

For new reord

```
var NewSession = (from s in Data.TableName
                  where s.Column1 == "test"
                  select new Table2Name { Column1 = s.Column1...etc }).ToList

Data.Table2Name.InsertAllOnSubmit(NewSession);
Data.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Tried it but it says, cannot implicitly convert 'System.Linq.iQueryable<MyDb.TableName>' to 'MyDb.TableName',an explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast ?)

Comment: Have you changed the delete to DeleteAllOnSubmit()instead of DeleteOnSubmit() ?

Comment: Incidentally TableName is also spelt TabelName in your example, but presuming it is a typo.

Comment: can i do the same thing to save this record into another table ?

Comment: No, you'll have to cast it to a new instance of the object you want select new MySecondObject { MyField1 = FirstObject.Field1 } etc